# How to put elements in array using VBScript on HTML web page (test automation)

Tags: html, vbscript, qtp

My HTML code:

```html
<input name="distance[]" required="required" type="text">
```

What would be the corresponding VBScript code to put elements in `distance[]` array one by one using QTP testing software.

I'm trying this code, but its not working:

```vb
IE.Document.All.("distance[0]").Value= "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you give something a name ending with a pair of square brackets doesn't make it an array. Text input fields return strings, not arrays. You need to split the value to get an actual array:

```html
<input name="distance" required="required" type="text">
```

```vb
distance = Split(IE.Documents.All.distance.Value)
WScript.Echo distance(0)
```

Comment: So i need to change my html code (to remove [] brackets) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if square brackets are valid name characters, but I would remove them just to be on the safe side.